# shouldInteractWithURL called twice on 3d touch

Tags: uitextview, 3dtouch

Below is the issue that i am trying to fix. I have a textView whose text is an attributed string with link attribute. On clicking the link, i should go to other screen. So, I am performing that screen navigation on shouldInteractWithURL() delegate method of the textView. Everything works fine except on force touching the textView, the next page is loading twice. That means shouldInteractWithURL() is called twice on force tap. I fixed it by checking the stack of the view controllers and if the last VC is the one that is about to load, I am returning from there. But, I wanted to know if there is any other solution other than this. Below is the code snippet

```
    textView.text = ""

    guard var str = myStr else {
        return nil
    }

    let linkAttribute = [NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "")!]
    var attributedStr:NSMutableAttributedString?
    if delay {
        str += " "
        attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)

        let ctaStr = kSuccessStr
        let ctaAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: ctaStr, attributes: linkAttribute)
        attributedStr!.appendAttributedString(ctaAttributedString)
    } else {
        let ctaStr = kFailedStr
        attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: ctaStr, attributes: linkAttribute)
    }
    textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()]
    textView.attributedText = attributedStr
    textView.delegate = thisTableViewDelegate

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool
{
    if let textLink = textView.text
    {
        if (textLink.rangeOfString(str1) != nil) ||
        (textLink.rangeOfString(str2) != nil)
        {
            showSignUpForm(self)
        }
        else
        {
            showSuccessfulForm()
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:interaction: instead.
Check if interaction != UITextItemInteractionInvokeDefaultAction and return NO.

See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618606-textview?language=objc

Comment: textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:interaction: is deprecated

Comment: I can't find a valid value for interaction

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem. The delegate method is still called twice, once with interaction `.preview` and then immediately after with interaction `.presentActions`. I regard this as a bug in iOS itself.

Answer (score 0):

I handle only `invokeDefaultAction` and it works for me:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    if interaction == .invokeDefaultAction {
        //do some stuff
    }
    return false
}
```